# How do I upload an image to my page?

Tags: jquery, html, image, upload

How do I upload an image to my site when Im running the website locally. I tried this:

```
$('#submitImage').click(function(){
  var img1 = $('#imageUpload').val();
  $('#container').append('<img src="'+img1+'"/>');
});
```

But apparently the path is incorrect, is this because the path has to be relative to my index.html file? How could I fix this?

Comment: What sort of code are you running server side?  'File upload' requires some cooperating server side code.

Comment: I have nothing on the server side. Like I said Im running this locally with no intention of ever uploading this to a server so I just need it to work on my computer. I think I just have to change the back slashes to forward slashes.

Comment: Your laptop is doing double duty - it's acting as a server when it serves out the HTML, and it's acting as a client when you run a web browser to read the HTML.  Without server side code (PHP, ASP.NET, etc) you'll never do a real "file upload".  You might be able to hack together a lookalike if you can live with the assumption that the web browser is running on the same computer as the web server (which is true on your laptop).

Comment: Yeaah thats what im tring to accomplish since I have no experience on any server side programming language. But I would be happy if you could point in the right direction to how actually upload a file to a server (my computer).

Comment: If you're on a Windows laptop, look into ASP.NET.  There's a free version of Visual Studio you can download.  If on something else, check out PHP.  There are about a dozen other server side coding languages and solutions out there.  You'll have to do some Googling to see what works best for you.  A bit of caution - there is a lot to this stuff, so don't expect to learn it in a week!